# How to initialize adapter with pojo class instead of list?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

Hello I am learning the new android jetpack with kotlin. While using recyclerview with binding we need to initialize the adapter with an empty list , most of the time I have seen people passing list to adapter. But how to do the same with a nested pojo class instead of a list ?

Here is the the data sample

> {"results":[{"gender":"female","name":{"title":"Ms","first":"Ines","last":"Hernandez"},"location":{"street":{"number":1495,"name":"Calle de Alcalá"},"city":"Málaga","state":"Melilla","country":"Spain","postcode":86664,"coordinates":{"latitude":"-17.4716","longitude":"106.6687"},"timezone":{"offset":"-5:00","description":"Eastern Time (US & Canada), Bogota, Lima"}},"email":"ines.hernandez@example.com","login":{"uuid":"66c3248d-d257-45b1-bd9c-3ebcba6e7b7a","username":"smallduck939","password":"maxxxx","salt":"kxEtQgmY","md5":"14e95cbbda70d692f74c5073a21b6a1e","sha1":"bf12732af070dd38e6418b31260ba10f74f14e94","sha256":"7f1b6be17c0bf339d6153c7c4379fd0d8564bf0cfa2f9e6ae9caef2a037f7e0a"},"dob":{"date":"1982-04-07T17:51:39.317Z","age":39},"registered":{"date":"2016-02-20T17:10:42.682Z","age":5},"phone":"964-947-469","cell":"677-793-075","id":{"name":"DNI","value":"96170049-S"},"picture":{"large":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/66.jpg","medium":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/66.jpg","thumbnail":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/66.jpg"},"nat":"ES"}]}

Here are my data classes

```
data class UserResponse(val results:ArrayList<User>?)
```

and the subsequent ones so you can see I have started the starting point with "results" key.

Now while declaring the adapter I need to pass a list like

```
 private val listAdapter = UserAdapter(arrayListOf())
```

and then declare something like

> //from another project

```
private val ListDataObserver = Observer<List<Animal>> {list-> list?.let { binding.animalList.visibility=View.VISIBLE
listAdapter.updateanimalList(it)}}
```

But you can see in the existing data the data is of type Single<> ie starting with a key, so how do I initialize the recyclerview in this case

```
private val listAdapter = UserAdapter(arrayListOf())
```

as the data class is not of type list ? Should I directly parse from here ?

> [{"gender":"female","name":{"title":"Ms","first":"Ines","last":"Hernande

Please help me with this as I am not able to initialize the recyclerview and use the observable subsequently.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the same list to the adapter object which you are getting from the observer, see below code

```
private val listAdapter = UserAdapter(arrayListOf<Animal>())

private val ListDataObserver = Observer< UserResponse> {userRes-> userRes?.let { binding.animalList.visibility=View.VISIBLE listAdapter.updateanimalList(it.result)}}
```

NOTE: Animal is the list that you are getting from the observer in the UserResponse object

Comment: where will I get this object userResponse from ? I am even that will need to be initialized right ? So how to do that ?

Comment: here is one catch that is you are using the User's list in this data class UserResponse(val results:ArrayList<User>?)

But in from observer you are getting Animal-> list private val ListDataObserver = Observer<List<Animal>> {list-> list?.let { binding.animalList.visibility=View.VISIBLE
listAdapter.updateanimalList(it)}}

please make it one either user or animal

and then if User is you list -> private val listAdapter = UserAdapter(arrayListO<User>f())

if Animal
and then if Animal is you list -> private val listAdapter = UserAdapter(arrayListO<Animal>f())

Comment: that is just an example from another project, I am yet to reach there.

Comment: so you can pass list to adapter as private val listAdapter = UserAdapter(arrayListOf<Animal>()) , animal is a list

and when you get data from the observer 
 private val ListDataObserver = Observer< UserResponse> {userRes-> userRes?.let { binding.animalList.visibility=View.VISIBLE
listAdapter.updateanimalList(it.result)}}

Comment: okay will try and let you know, and mark your answer thanks.

Comment: please update your answer , with the comment answer, i will mark it as correct. Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer please mark it correct